# How can I configure LiteDb to accept DateTimeOffset as dictionary key?

Tags: litedb

Given the following sample:

```
class Data
{ 
    public Dictionary<DateTimeOffset, string> Dict { get; set; }
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var dbf = Path.GetTempFileName();
    
    try
    {
        using var db = new LiteDatabase(dbf);

        var datas = db.GetCollection<Data>();

        var data = new Data
        {
            Dict = new() { { DateTimeOffset.Now, "apple" }, {DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1), "pear"} }
        };
        
        datas.Upsert(data);
        
        var got = datas.FindById(data.Id);
        
        got.Dump();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Dump();
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(dbf);
    }   
}
```

The data is persisted as expected, but I am getting `Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'.` when trying to retrieve the data.

Can I specify somehow the serializer for the key? I worked it around by storing the UNIX Epoch instead, but it is counterintuitive to work with it like that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, LiteDB uses **BsonValue** as internal storage format, and by default, it may not handle complex types like `DateTimeOffset` as keys in a dictionary.

So you can create a custom serializer for `DateTimeOffset` keys, and LiteDB allows you to register custom serializers using the `BsonMapper.Global`

For example:

```
BsonMapper.Global.RegisterType(
    serialize: key => key.ToString(), // Convert DateTimeOffset to string for serialization.
    deserialize: bson => DateTimeOffset.Parse(bson.AsString) // Parse string back to DateTimeOffset during deserialization.
);
```

By registering this custom serializer **before** interacting with LiteDB database, you can ensure that `DateTimeOffset` keys are properly serialized and deserialized.

Comment: I have already tried the registration. It does not work. Maybe because it has some additional constraints to dictionaries. In the docs there is stated: *For IDictionary<K, T>, K key must be String or a simple type (convertible using Convert.ToString(..)* But `Convert.ToString` works for `DateTimeOffset`, however `Convert.ChangeType` throws the exact same exception. Works with plain `DateTime` though....

Comment: It has most likely nothing to do with complexity. They are both just structs. `DateTime` is `IConvertible`, but `DateTimeOffset` is not :(